# Issues Mounting CIFS Share using systemd

Tags: samba, systemd, cifs

I'm having trouble getting a CIFS share to properly mount at boot using a systemd .mount file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount CIFS movies folder
Requires=network-online.target
After=network-online.service

[Mount]
What=//192.168.0.103/movies
Where=/media/movies
Options=rw,cache=none,uid=<userid>,gid=<groupid>,credentials=/etc/samba/.smbcreds,sec=ntlmv2,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0
Type=cifs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- The error reported is mount 2 - No such file or directory. The `Where` portion for sure exists and has proper permissions
- If I manually start the unit after I login, without doing anything else, the mount completes without trouble
- The remote server is for sure up, with both computers connected via wired, so the share name should be findable

My best guess would be I need something else in the `After` or `Requires`, but what that could be, I do not know. It seems like this should only require the network, given that the mount point exists.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the service is executing *before* the folder is available and ready to mount

You'd need to specify in the file to wait on and start after (AFTER= ) the service that connects the CIFS share

Comment: Is that before the filesystem folder is ready?  Ie After=/media/movies or something similar?

Comment: @stumpylog it needs to wait until after whatever service mounts CIFS shares. Maybe you should go for a @ reboot root crontab instead, it'd be easier